# Magento cache adds content twice

Tags: php, magento, caching

I have Magento CE 1.7.0.2 site with a custom created theme.

**Problem is:** Only when I turn on cache - some content on page "doubles". So footer showed on page again in the end of the page.

**Screen:** http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/3038/eqv7.jpg 
(`Shop By` block and footer doubled, as you see in the bottom)

Any suggestions how to fix? Or where to start looking at?

Thanks for any help,
Stanislav.

P.S. 
Code of "1-column.phtml" (this page template PHTML)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div class="category-page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <div class="bread" style="margin-top:40px"></div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
        <div class="product-page" style="min-height:auto;">
            <div class="content_main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bread2"></div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_block') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you test the result with `echo $this->getChildHtml('footer')` or `echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end')` commented out, to see which one of those calls is displaying the double content ?

Comment: @blmage this one: `echo $this->getChildHtml('footer')`

Comment: **`footer`** block - is just text with copyrights and nothing more. just 2 lines of `HTML`. **`footer_block`** - is menu, that is doubled.

Comment: In the source of your website, the additional content is placed outside `<div class="wrapper"></div>`, so there must be something that is not working well between the definition and/or uses of the `footer` block and the layout cache, can you paste here the places where the `footer` block is referenced in your layout files ?

Comment: @blmage here they are. just default base theme files with some modifications:


1. `catalog.xml`: http://pastebin.com/SpwrTvcm
2. `page.xml`: http://pastebin.com/Nq09Pckp

Comment: @blmage also I've renamed block "custom_footer_block" - same issue happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout, you have two footer blocks, which use the same `page/html_footer` type. Or, this block type is not intended to be used more than one time on the same page, the first content it will display will be cached and returned on the later calls (see `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer::getCacheKeyInfo()`). So, for one of your footer blocks, you should use another block type (this should be `footer_block`, as it's the one not existing in base Magento).

On a side note, your `footer_block` block is defined two times, once in `page.xml` and once in `catalog.xml`, and both of your footer blocks contain a child named `bottom.container`, so you could try to remove it from the definition of `footer_block`.

Comment: oh, damn! you are right. renamed `page/html_footer` to `page/html` - all works fine! thanks a lot! I'll keep it in my for next time.